# Where is my static context?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm brand new to android programming and I'm trying to use a gridviewpager with fragments. My code is:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid);
    final Resources res = getResources();
    GridViewPager pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.gridpager);
    pager.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
        @Override
        public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
            // Adjust page margins:
            //   A little extra horizontal spacing between pages looks a bit
            //   less crowded on a round display.
            final boolean round = insets.isRound();
            int rowMargin = res.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.page_row_margin);
            int colMargin = res.getDimensionPixelOffset(round ?
                    R.dimen.page_column_margin_round : R.dimen.page_column_margin);
            pager.setPageMargins(rowMargin, colMargin);

            // GridViewPager relies on insets to properly handle
            // layout for round displays. They must be explicitly
            // applied since this listener has taken them over.
            pager.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
            return insets;
        }
    });
//        MyPagerAdapter adapter=new MyPagerAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(Activity.getFragmentManager()));
}

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

            case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
            case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
            case 2: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 2");
            default: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
  }
}
```

I've collapsed some to be concise. The error is in this line:

```
 pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(Activity.getFragmentManager()));
```

This returns the error:

> Non-static method 'getFragmentManager()' cannot be referenced from a static context

But I don't know what is static in my code. I've tried assigning everything I can think of to variables but still can't get this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activity` is the name of a class. By stating `Activity.getFragmentManager()`, you are attempting to call a method on the class itself rather than a specific instance of the class.

In your case, you don't need the `Activity.` section at all - just call `getFragmentManager()` itself:

```
pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So now I get a new error in the same place saying that MyPagerAdapter (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager) in MyPagerAdapter cannot be applied to (android.app.FragmentManager). I have the support library installed (I think), so what does this mean?

Comment: You somewhat have a mishmash of things going on at the moment: the `Activity` code you have is an Android Wear app, but the `FragmentPagerAdapter` is for phone Android apps. If you meant to write a Wearable app, you need to implement a `android.support.wearable.view.FragmentGridPagerAdapter` such as [the sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/GridViewPager/Wearable/src/com.example.android.wearable.gridviewpager/SampleGridPagerAdapter.html) rather than `FragmentPagerAdapter`. If you meant to write a phone/tablet app, you need to use `FragmentActivity` and `getSupportFragmentManager`.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot. Haha this is what I get for taking everything off forums. (I am trying to make a wearable app, just in full screen and without cards, by the way.)

Comment: If this helped answer your initial question, make sure to accept it. Best of luck building your app!